# Does AtomicReference.compareAndSet(old,new) guarantees old.field wasn't change?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomicreference

Does `AtomicReference.compareAndSet(old,new)` guarantee

1. `old.field` wasn't change?
2. Or it just guarantees `old` wasn't
   reassign to a new object?

if 2 is true, does it mean `AtomicReference` is useful only with immutable objects like `String`? (Because in case of mutability of `old` the `old.field` changes are lost with a **successfully** `compareAndSet`)

Comment: It's `AtomicReference.compareAndSet(expect,update)`, not `(old,new)`

Comment: ok, does expect guarantee no fields were changed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AtomicReference` *only* checks reference equality, and does not check for changes to fields.

As a result, it is primarily only useful with immutable types.

Comment: So is it useful only with immutable objects like String? Because in case of mutability of old the old.field changes are lost with a successfully compareAndSet

Comment: Yes, basically.